# When $C_k(X,2)$ is Baire?

Tags: gn.general-topology

$C_k(X,2)$ is the family of all continuous function from $X$ to $\{0,1\}$ with compact-open topology.
 for which kind of topological spaces $C_k(X,2)$ is Baire or meager?
 Or is there something related?

Comment: If $X$ is connected, your set is a finite one of size $2$.